# Why didn't Hippolyta lift the horse?

Tags: plot-explanation, dc-extended-universe, justice-league, zack-snyders-justice-league

In the scene from *Justice League* where Steppenwolf attacks Themyscira and Hippolyta is riding the horse with another Amazon carrying the mother box, when Steppenwolf strikes them, **why did Hippolyta not lift the horse to help the other Amazon that was stuck under the horse?**

I assume she has superhuman strength as per what the Wiki says; I'd even say the Amazon that was stuck has superhuman strength too, but maybe she was tired or couldn't draw enough strength when she was stuck. So why didn't the queen help?

This is the scene I'm referring to:

[image: GIF of the scene described above]

Comment: *"I assume she has superhuman strength"* - what wiki, you didn't link it? I don't think there is any evidence that the amazons have superhuman strength by default. Certainly they are exceptionally gifted athletes an warriors but Diana is a demigod which is where her strength comes from.

Comment: @Paulie_D - This says she possesses "enhanced strength".  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hippolyta_(DC_Comics)#Powers_and_abilities

Comment: That's the comics version.....not the movie one.

Comment: @Paulie_D But it's weird if they strip the queen's abilities in the movies and Amazonian race is different with human race like the Atlantean. Also in DCEU wiki, though it's fan base. They are still described as 'superhuman warriors' and their trainings as shown in the Wonder Woman 1984 are beyond human level. It wont make sense if they make Amazons a regular human race when they show separate protectors during the Snyder Cut.

Comment: also there is **evidence** that Amazons have superhuman strength base on the comics which is where the movie was based and what is shown in some clips in Wonder Woman movie. If you contest that movie was different, nah, between Amazon as a superior race and an ordinary race, then the latter has no evidence.

Comment: It's hard to answer these "why did _X_ NOT do _Y_" questions. It could be the character had a reason / there was no time for the expected action, or the scene was scripted that way to help the plot.

Answer (score 2):

To elaborate on the existing answer by MCU And You Film Blog: **if someone is being crushed beneath a heavy weight, simply lifting the weight off of them will not necessarily save their life.**

There is a known medical phenomenon called "[crush syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crush_syndrome)". As a person is crushed, and their blood supply is cut off, their muscles break down and release toxic byproducts. Suddenly releasing the pressure causes these byproducts to be released into the person's bloodstream, with invariably fatal results.

If we assume that the trapped Amazon was indeed being crushed to death beneath her own horse, then simply lifting the horse off of her wouldn't have helped. The only way to treat crush syndrome is to slowly and gradually release the pressure, to give the body time to adapt, and Hippolyta didn't have time for such a gradual release because, as you said, Steppenwolf was *right there*, and would have just killed them both long before she had finished.

So in short, there doesn't seem to have been anything Hippolyta could have done under the circumstances that would have saved that poor Amazon's life.

Answer (score 1):

The queen did help; she offers compassion (in the moment of her own personal peril) lifting the horse would not have saved her life.